# How to show products categorized in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, nosql, aggregation-framework

I have a MongoDB collection name as 'products', which have these documents:

```
{productName: "ABC", category: "cat1"}
{productName: "DEF", category: "cat2"}
{productName: "GHI", category: "cat3"}
{productName: "JKL", category: "cat1"}
{productName: "MNO", category: "cat2"}
{productName: "PQR", category: "cat3"}
```

I want to show products by category. Here is my desired output:

```
[
    {_id: {category: 'cat1'}, {products: [{productName: "ABC"}, {productName: "JKL"}]}},
    {_id: {category: 'cat2'}, {products: [{productName: "DEF"}, {productName: "MNO"}]}},
    {_id: {category: 'cat3'}, {products: [{productName: "GHI"}, {productName: "PQR"}]}}
]
```

I have written query to group theme by category. Here is the code:

```
db.products.aggregate([
    {$group: {_id: {category: "$category"}}}
])
```

How to solve my problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your approach with a `$group` on `$category` was good.
You just need to use an [aggregation operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/) in the stage.

With `$push`, you can create a list of `products`

```
[
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$category",
      products: {
        $push: {
          "productName": "$productName"
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

try it [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/S1Pa-FKmo_d)

Comment: Thanks for the solution. Now if I want to **sort** the _products_ array with respect to time, what should I do?